# Finding missing value from two different data in [R]

Tags: r

I have two data set here. One is here like this.

```
>sp2
# A tibble: 1,822 x 3
         Date  Hour  Price
       <dttm> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2015-12-31     2  17.15
 2 2015-12-30     2  26.23
 3 2015-12-29     2  23.01
 4 2015-12-28     2  20.58
 5 2015-12-27     2  14.09
 6 2015-12-26     2 -66.02
 7 2015-12-25     2  -4.50
 8 2015-12-24     2  18.32
 9 2015-12-23     2   0.43
10 2015-12-22     2 -81.04
# ... with 1,812 more rows
```

The other data I have is as below:

```
> head(da2)
   LiefertagDeliveryDate Price Hour
1:            2015-12-31 22.73    2
2:            2015-12-30 32.30    2
3:            2015-12-29 43.38    2
4:            2015-12-28 48.03    2
5:            2015-12-27 45.08    2
6:            2015-12-26 25.50    2
```

Thing is, the sp2 has 1822 observations and da2 has 1826 observations. I want to find out what are the 4 observations discrepancy and what are the info of those 4 observations. People suggested me to use `setdiff`. But When I used it, it showed just weird numbers like

```
[1] 1451520000 1451433600 1451347200 1451260800 1451174400 1451088000 1451001600 1450915200 1450828800 1450742400 1450656000 1450569600 1450483200 1450396800
[15] 1450310400 1450224000 1450137600 1450051200 1449964800 1449878400 1449792000 1449705600 1449619200 1449532800 1449446400 1449360000 1449273600 1449187200
```

I do not know what the problem is. Is it maybe because date of sp2 property is not "Date"? It shows like this:

```
class(sp2$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I really do not know what is problem. I can send my data to people but I do not know how to send since I just joined the community.

Comment: Did you try `da2[!da2[['LiefertagDeliveryDate']] %in% sp2[['Date']], ]` ?

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Yes. It shows me stuff but I do not think it is what I want.

Comment: Please note the **Details** section of `?setdiff`: "`setdiff` [...] appl[ies] `as.vector` to their arguments". Check `class(Sys.time())` and `class(as.vector(Sys.time()))`.